# jQuery dropdown menu on click with clickable(on second click) parent

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, click, modernizr

I'm trying to create a simple navigation menu with dropdowns. I set 'data-dropdown' attribute to 'opened' or 'closed' with jQuery for late CSS use. I use 'Modernizr.touchevents' to decide on hover/click behaviour. Here's my code:

```
(function ($) {

    "use strict";

    var menu = $('.navbar .menu');

    // Return early if there's no menu
    if ( ! menu ) {
        return;
    }

    var dropdownLi = menu.find('.menu-item-has-children');
    var dropdownLink = menu.find('.menu-item-has-children > a');

    // Return early if there's no dropdown
    if ( ! dropdownLi ) {
        return;
    }

    // Set attr to all dropdowns by default
    dropdownLi.attr('data-dropdown', 'closed');

     // Use modernizr to decide on touch/hover behaviour
    if (Modernizr.touchevents) {

        dropdownLink.click(function(event) {

            // Set 'data-dropdown' attr to 'opened'
            $(this).parent().attr('data-dropdown', 'opened');

            // Set 'data-dropdown' attr on other submeus to 'closed'
            $(this).parent().siblings().attr('data-dropdown', 'closed');

            // Set 'data-dropdown' attr on other nested subenus to 'closed'
            $(this).parent().siblings().find('.menu-item-has-children').attr('data-dropdown', 'closed');

            // Prevent default click
            return false;
            // event.preventDefault();
            // event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        });

        // Close all menus on scroll
        $('.site-wrapper').scroll(function () {
            dropdownLi.attr('data-dropdown', 'closed');
        });

        // Close all dropdowns when clicked anywhere
        $(document).click(function () {
            dropdownLi.attr('data-dropdown', 'closed');
        });

    } else { // Now hover behaviour

        dropdownLi.each(function() {

            $(this).mouseenter(function () {
                $(this).attr('data-dropdown', 'opened');
            });

            $(this).mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).attr('data-dropdown', 'closed');
            });

        });

        // Prevent default click if there's just a `#` instead of a link
        dropdownLink.on('click', function(){
            if ( this.href.indexOf('#') != -1 ) {
                return false;
                // event.preventDefault();
                // event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        });

    }


})(jQuery);
```

And now the problem. A 'dropdownLink' could have a valid href attribute ( not # ). In this case, I need it to act like it should on the second click. So, while on a touch device, the first click opens a dropdown, and second sends us to the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm understanding your issue correctly(it's a bit tricky without the HTML), you simply just need an extra check like so(i havn't verified it as i don't have your HTML):

```
...

dropdownLink.click(function(event) {

    if($(this).parent().attr('data-dropdown') != 'opened') {

          // Set 'data-dropdown' attr to 'opened'
          $(this).parent().attr('data-dropdown', 'opened');

...
```

So if the menu isn't opened it will do that and return false(thereby avoiding going to the URL) and then the second time it is being clicked the link will get handled...

Added fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fekadgjr/

Comment: Correct your answer is! Now I'm questioning myself how I didn't get it on my own, so obvious. Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes you just stare at it for too long and then get lost in your own thoughts! Glad i could help :)